# Encrypted Windows Backup to NAS without third party tools?

Tags: windows-10, backup, encryption

Is there any way using Windows 10's native tools to create a regular backup to an (unencrypted) Network storage such that other users that have access to this storage have no way to access the backed up data (ie. have the backup data be encrypted)

Comment: You might be able to use EFS on a single folder on the NAS, but if multiple backups for different machine are in the same root folder, that solution won't work.  I don't believe there is a way to encrypt the backup itself, the built-in tool, does not have that feature.

Answer (score 1):

The native backup tools in Windows don't do encryption as far as I know.
That leaves, to my knowledge just 2 workarounds, which both require the NAS to have certain features available:

1. If the shared filesystem on the NAS supports folder-encryption put the backup in a encrypted folder on the NAS share. This has the drawback that the backup needs to be made under the same user-credentials that created the encrypted folder in the first place (e.g. could complicate unattended backups when the user is not logged in to the computer.)
2. If the NAS can act as an iSCSI target you can create an iSCSI volume and map that as a local disk onto the computer. At that point you treat the extra disk as any other local disk: You can BitLocker that disk, use VeraCrypt on it or just use NTFS with encryption to protect the content. Then make the backups to that disk. Same drawbacks might apply: Unlocking the disk may require user-interaction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! What about putting a VHD file onto the nas and then using bitlocker on the mounted VHD and use this drive then as backup? Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @user1282931 That would probably work as well, but I would not do it. Mounting a VHD from a network share would be extremely slow and runs a major risk of corrupting the VHD, because it was never intended to be used that way. The merest network hickup could potentially corrupt the backup, possibly without any indication that it happened. iSCSI is designed to be used in this way and is very robust. Would be a lot faster and MUCH reliable. (And for me: reliability is the foremost consideration when it comes to backups.)